# Sunan Abu Dawud 4358 Authenticity

Tags: hadith, authenticity

On sunnah.com the Hadith is graded as Hasan in chain. Does that mean the Hadith is not truly Hasan? Meaning, it is only Hasan in chain but the Matn (content) is defective?

https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4358

Answer (score 1):

The next hadeeth is about the same thing. Sheikh Albaani has declared this one Saheeh:

> On the day of the conquest of Mecca, Abdullah ibn Sa'd ibn AbuSarh hid
> himself with Uthman ibn Affan.
>
> He brought him and made him stand before the Prophet (ﷺ), and said:
> Accept the allegiance of Abdullah, Messenger of Allah! He raised his
> head and looked at him three times, refusing him each time, but
> accepted his allegiance after the third time.
>
> Then turning to his companions, he said: Was not there a wise man
> among you who would stand up to him when he saw that I had withheld my
> hand from accepting his allegiance, and kill him?
>
> They said: We did not know what you had in your heart, Messenger of
> Allah! Why did you not give us a signal with your eye?
>
> He said: It is not advisable for a Prophet to play deceptive tricks
> with the eyes.

https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4359

Comment: According to respected hadith scholar Shuayb Al-Arna'ut, the chain of narration for Sunan Abi Dawud 4359 is hasan. So it is not agreed upon by hadith scholars that this hadith is authentic.

https://shamela.ws/book/117359/3653#p1
https://shamela.ws/book/117359/2208#p1

Comment: Hassan is a type of authentic hadith.

Comment: No it isn't. Hasan means that the isnad has some/slight weakness but not as many weaknesses as a "daif" hadith. Back then, all hadiths, that weren't sahih were classified as daif, but hadith scholars felt that it'd be worth not clumping hadiths that are only slightly weak with those that are flat out false. 

Some scholars use hasan hadiths and some do not in forming their opinions and other areas of Islam. But you cannot make hasan equivalent to sahih which doesn't have any weaknesses (assuming all hadith scholars agree that a hadith is sahih).

Comment: Check out these links regarding hadith science and what hasan hadiths are:

https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/358777/definition-of-hasan-and-hasan-ghareeb-hadeeth

https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/authenticating-hadith-and-the-history-of-hadith-criticism

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/126978/categories-of-hadeeth Then they divided the accepted hadeeths into a number of categories: 1. Saheeh: if it fulfilled the highest conditions of acceptability. 2. Hasan: if it fulfilled the minimal conditions of acceptability.

Comment: https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hadith/difference-sahih-hassan-daif-hadith/: Sahih and hasan hadith, according to the hadith scholars (muhaddithun) are “accepted” (maqbul), and da‘if hadith are “rejected” (mardud) ... A hasan hadith fulfills the same criteria as the sahih hadith except that its narrators’ exactness is less than the exactness found in narrators of sahih hadith. ... Like the sahih hadith, the fuqaha (jurists) and most of the muhaddithun accept that the hasan hadith can also be used for evidence.

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/86128/some-kinds-of-hadith Hadith Hasan Lighairihi is an acceptable Hadith so, the scholars are agreed that it should be accepted and should be acted according to it.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/79163/conditions-of-a-saheeh-sound-hadeeth Most of the scholars of hadeeth do not differentiate between hasan and saheeh.

Comment: You just proved what I was informing you of. It isn't unanimous among scholars the acceptance of hasan hadiths usage.

Also, a hasan hadith's isnad means that at least one narrator has bad/inaccurate memory. Additionally many schools in Islam would only use hasan hadiths in absence of stronger evidence such as Quran and sahih hadiths. 

Regarding OP's question, the hadith is repeated with a chain of narration that was deemed Authentic by Muhadith Al-Hakim in Al-Mustadrak 3/45.

https://shamela.ws/book/117359/3653#p1

Comment: Furthermore, if a historical event is only described in hasan hadiths or weaker then it is questionable entirely. Scholars are generally lenient when hadiths describe virtues but are more strict when it comes to historical events, ascribing mandatory acts in Islam, legal theory, etc.

Comment: Actually you are wrong since you negated me and said Hassan is not authentic while I showed you that Hassan is a type of authentic or acceptable hadith. You said that a hadith which is not sahih was classed as daif while I showed you that most scholars do not differentiate between sahih and hasan. And you said "some" scholars use hasan hadith while I proved that a majority of them do so. The hadith I have given is also labelled by Al-Hakim and as Sahih and in reality the rijaal of this hadith are rijaal of sahih Muslim.

Comment: Also both hadith mean the same thing that prophet wanted this man dead, so if you accept one is sahih then argument is pointless. I don't have more time to waste on you.

Comment: "Some scholars use hasan hadiths and some do not in forming their opinions and other areas of Islam. But you cannot make hasan equivalent to sahih which doesn't have any weaknesses (assuming all hadith scholars agree that a hadith is sahih)." This is still true. 

And no, most hadith scholars don't consider sahih and hasan to be the same exact thing. If that was the case, there wouldn't be these two different words in the first place. I've given you valid sources, not anonymous Islamqa articles.

Comment: Again, The the usage of hasan hadiths generally comes after there's no stronger evidence from the Quran or sahih hadiths by most Islamic schools. I'm telling you there is stronger evidence, a sahih hadith. So thank me instead, stop making sahih and hasan equivalent, understand when hasan hadiths and tertiary sources of Islamic law are used, and get off of your high horse because you've proven absolutely nothing I said was incorrect. Scholars are generally lenient when hadiths describe virtues but are stricter when it comes to events, ascribing mandatory acts in Islam, legal theory, etc.

Comment: Hasan isn't authentic. Sahih is authentic, hasan is weaker than authentic. You didn't prove that. Hasan is attributed to "fair" or "good" because is still has weakness. Authentic, sahih, means no weakness found.

Comment: Hasan is acceptable and authentic although it is less authentic than sahih. It is only a daif hadith which can only be used in virtues and even then somne types of daif like mursal are acceptable according to a lot of ulema. I have given you sources and quotes, you have only given me links and even those links do not say wht you are preaching, like the article from yaqeeninstitute says: **All Sunni scholars have accepted both ṣaḥīḥ and ḥasan hadiths as compelling proofs in matters of law.** If you wish to revel in your ignorance then be by guest

Comment: Finish the rest of the sentence from the yaqeen article, **The subject of theology was more contested, and there was prolonged debate over whether hadiths narrated through a handful of isnāds were reliable enough to inform Islamic dogma.** And I stated in my previous comments "Some scholars use hasan hadiths and some do not in forming their opinions and other areas of Islam" and "the usage of hasan hadiths generally comes after there's no stronger evidence from the Quran or sahih hadiths by most Islamic schools" which are still true.

Comment: furthermore and this is still true as well "and "Scholars are generally lenient when hadiths describe virtues but are more strict when it comes to historical events, ascribing mandatory acts in Islam, legal theory, etc." **Ahl al-ḥadīth jurists like al-Shāfiʿī, his student Ibn Ḥanbal, and his student al-Bukhārī understood well that one could not simply take every hadith that one heard from the Prophet ﷺ as the law. Even if a legal hadith was authentic**

I'm just disagreeing with you that "Hassan is a type of authentic hadith" which is you what you wrote.

Answer (score -1):

The hadith according to respected hadith scholar Shuayb Al-Arna'ut is Saheeh Ligharihi. This means that this hadith by itself, from its isnad only, is not sahih but that this same hadith is repeated somewhere else with a sahih isnad. For this hadith, is is repeated in Al-Mustadrak 3/45 with a sahih isnad according to Al-Hakim.

- [كتاب سنن أبي داود - ت الأرنؤوط   ٤٣٥٨](https://shamela.ws/book/117359/3653#p1)

Al-Albani also concurs with this as he put this hadith in his "Sahih Abi Dawud" book of hadiths and marked the isnad as hasan.

- [dorar search](https://www.dorar.net/hadith/search?q=%D8%A3%D9%86+%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%AA%D9%84+%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%8C+%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D9%84%D9%87+%D8%B9%D8%AB%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86+%D8%A8%D9%86+%D8%B9%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%8C+%D9%81%D8%A3%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87+%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87+-+%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87+%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87+%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85&st=w&xclude=&rawi%5B%5D=#home)

Isnad means chain of narration in case you did not know.

Furthermore, I'd like to mention that matn criticism is separate from isnad criticism. There have been hadiths where their isnads were considered authentic but hadith scholars completely ignored them due to their matn. Imam al-Bukhari himself rejected perfectly authentic hadiths when he considered their contents to be ridiculous, as in a hadith that claimed something would happen within 200 years that never happened.

For more info on this topic, you can check out this paper by Muslim scholar
Dr. Jonathan AC Brown:

[How We Know Early Ḥadīth Critics Did Matn
Criticism and Why It’s So Hard to Find](https://www.drjonathanbrown.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/How-We-Know-Early-Hadith-Critics-Did-Matn-Criticism-and-Why-Its-So-Hard-to-Find.pdf)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please mention why.